# Working with Ruby on Rails 3.2 and Mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

Is there an actual gem or plugin for working with the mailchimp API in ruby on rails projects?

I tried the gems Gibbon and Hominid. But I'm not happy with them.

Comment: You can try the [official gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mailchimp) or [ChimpActions](http://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/chimpactions-ruby-gem).  What didn't you like about Hominid?

Comment: THanks for your comment. I think i did not understand how it works with hominid. TRying  a little bit and it works in the first step while i look into the API reference.